Finiteness of a generalization of the class number of a number field
Let $f(x)$ be an irreducible monic integral polynomial with root $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$. A classical result of Latimer and MacDuffee asserts that there is a bijection between similarity classes of integer matrices with characteristic polynomial $f(x)$ and the ideal class monoid of the $\mathbb{Z}$-order $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. David Husert's dissertation "Similarity of Integer Matrices" generalizes this correspondence to the case of integer matrices with squarefree minimal polynomials and arbitrary characteristic polynomials.
Let me introduce some of the notation used in Husert's thesis. Let $\mathcal{K} = \bigoplus_{i=1}^{s} K_i$ denote the direct sum of finitely many number fields. Let $\textbf{n} = (n_1, \ldots , n_s)$ be a tuple of non-negative integers. Define $\mathcal{K}^{\textbf{n}} = \bigoplus_{i=1}^{s} {K_i}^{n_i}$ and $\mathcal{M}(\textbf{n}, \mathcal{K}) = \bigoplus_{i=1}^{s} Mat(n_i, K_i)$. Let $\mathcal{O}$ be a $\mathbb{Z}$-order in $\mathcal{K}$. We say $U$ is a full $\mathcal{O}$-module in $\mathcal{K}^{\textbf{n}}$ if $U$ is a finitely generated $\mathcal{O}$-submodule of $\mathcal{K}^{\textbf{n}}$ that spans $\mathcal{K}^{\textbf{n}}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Note that $\mathcal{K}$ acts on $\mathcal{K}^{\textbf{n}}$ componentwise, so it makes sense to talk about an $\mathcal{O}$-submodule of $\mathcal{K}^{\textbf{n}}$.
Let $\alpha = (\alpha_1, \ldots , \alpha_s)$ be a tuple of algebraic integers with minimal polynomials $m_{\alpha_i}(x)$. The generalized Latimer-MacDuffee theorem asserts that there is a bijection between integer matrices with characteristic polynomial $\chi(x) = m_{\alpha_1}(x)^{n_1} \cdots m_{\alpha_s}(x)^{n_s}$ and minimal polynomial $\mu(x) = m_{\alpha_1}(x) \cdots m_{\alpha_s}(x)$, and the set of isomorphism classes of full $\mathcal{O}$-modules in $\mathcal{K}^{\textbf{n}}$, where $\mathcal{K} = \bigoplus_{i=1}^{s} \mathbb{Q}(\alpha_i)$ and $\mathcal{O} = \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$. It may be relevant to note that a simple proposition tells us that two full $\mathcal{O}$-modules $U$ and $B$ are isomorphic if and only if there exists $\Gamma \in GL(\textbf{n}, \mathcal{K})$ such that $\Gamma U = B$. Here, $GL(\textbf{n}, \mathcal{K})$ is the units of the direct sum of matrix algebras, which we may view as block diagonal matrices with invertible blocks (under this identification, the action on $\mathcal{K}^{\textbf{n}}$ is clear).
I am interested in integer matrices, and as such I would like to prove that the number of full $\mathcal{O}$-module classes in $\mathcal{K}^{\textbf{n}}$ is finite in the general case of $\mathcal{K}$ being a finite direct sum of number fields and $\mathcal{O}$ a $\mathbb{Z}$-order in $\mathcal{K}$. In the case that $\mathcal{O} = \mathcal{O}_\mathcal{K}$ is the unique maximal order in $\mathcal{K}$, any full $\mathcal{O}$-module may be written as the direct sum of modules over the rings of integers of number fields, and we may use the structure of finitely generated modules over a Dedekind domain to prove that the number of $\mathcal{O}$-module classes is precisely the product of the class numbers of the number fields $K_i$. However, in general, $\mathcal{O}$ need not be maximal nor decompose as the direct sum of its components.
So, my question is the following: Is it true that the number of isomorphism classes of $\mathcal{O}$-module classes in $\mathcal{K}^{\textbf{n}}$ is finite (I suspect that it is), and how do we prove this result? Note that in the case $\mathcal{K}$ is a number field and $\textbf{n} = (1)$, this is simply the finiteness of the ideal class monoid of an order of a number field.
My attempts and ideas:
Following the discussion here: (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72213/ideal-classes-and-integral-similarity) I read Theorem 20.6 in Curtis and Reiner's representation theory text. I believe that the proof given there can be adapted to give a proof of the desired case when $\textbf{n} = (1, \ldots , 1)$. Indeed, in the notation of Curtis-Reiner, if we take $L = \mathcal{K}$ as the direct sum of number fields, and $L_0 = \mathcal{O}$, I think that we can more or less copy the proof presented in their text. While $\mathcal{K}$ is obviously not a skewfield, only Lemma 20.12 seems to use this condition, and I believe we can modify the proof of Lemma 20.10 to produce a nonzerodivisor with bounded norm (instead of merely nonzero) and then proceed identically.
However, I have been unable to extend this to the general case of $\textbf{n} = (n_1, \ldots , n_s)$. One idea I've tried is induction on the sum $n_1 + \cdots + n_s$. If $U \subseteq \mathcal{K}^{\textbf{n}}$ is a full $\mathcal{O}$-module, then $U \subseteq \bigoplus_{i} \pi_i(U)$ may be viewed as an $\mathcal{O}$-submodule of the direct sum of its projections onto each component. When $\textbf{n} = (1, \ldots, 1)$, there are only finitely many isomorphism classes (provided my adaptation of Curtis-Reiner holds), so each $\mathcal{O}$-submodule of $\mathcal{K}$ has finitely many submodules up to isomorphism. We can assume that each $\mathcal{O}$-module in $\mathcal{K}^{\textbf{n}}$ has finitely many submodules up to isomorphism then attempt to prove the inductive step using the observation about projections. The projections of $U$ onto each component will have finitely many submodules by induction and $U$ is isomorphic to a submodule of their direct sum. However, I'm not sure if it is the case that the direct sum of modules, each with finitely many isomorphism classes of submodules, has finitely many isomorphism classes of submodules itself.
One possible simplification is the following: Since $\mathcal{O}$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module, it is Noetherian. Thus, any $\mathcal{O}$-module may be written as a finite direct sum of indecomposable modules. Therefore, it would suffice to show that there are only finitely many isomorphism classes of indecomposable modules. While researching this approach, I came across the term "orders of finite lattice type," which may mean something to someone more experienced than I.
Finally, I think that the Jordan-Zassenhaus theorem (see, for example, Reiner's "Maximal Orders") is quite relevant to this situation, but I do not have enough background knowledge to understand it.
This is my first time asking a question here, so I apologize if my question does not meet some of the guidelines. Also, I am a fourth year undergraduate student, so I would greatly appreciate answers that are comprehensible to the non-expert. Thanks in advance for your responses!

A very nice first question! I think you did great as far as the guidelines go, this is a clear question and a clear explanation of why you're interested and what you've done so far.

Also, for that first cited theorem of Latimer and MacDuffee I assume you need $f$ to be irreducible?

Yes, good catch! I edited the original post.

It is true that the number of isomorphism classes of full $\mathcal{O}$-modules in $\mathcal{K}^{\textbf{n}}$ is finite. The result is a special case of the Jordan-Zassenhaus Theorem. For future readers, let me provide two references which prove this theorem.
In Curtis and Reiner's "Representation Theory of Finite Groups and Associative Algebras," the Jordan-Zassenhaus Theorem is Theorem 79.1. The proof uses the earlier, easier to prove Theorem 20.6, along with the Artin-Wedderburn theorem, and some very basic results on group cohomology, all of which can be found in earlier sections of the text. I found the proof to be relatively easy to follow and self-contained, but not particularly well motivated. Curtis and Reiner establish the result for $\mathbb{Z}$-orders (which is enough for my purposes), but the result holds in greater generality. Since the proof spans more than five pages, I will not attempt to reproduce it here. An interesting corollary of the result is that the number of isomorphism classes of $k$-dimensional integral representations of a finite group $G$ is finite. Indeed, we can consider the $\mathbb{Z}$-order $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ in $\mathbb{Q}[G]$ and apply Jordan-Zassenhaus. I think this special case is another result that is itself sometimes called the Jordan-Zassenhaus Theorem.
In Reiner's "Maximal Orders," Jordan-Zassenhaus can be found as Theorem 26.4. Here, the result is proved for orders over a Dedekind domain whose field of fractions is a global field. The proof is less than a page, but draws on several technical lemmas and many results proved throughout the earlier chapters. This was the version I originally encountered, and I have not been able to understand the details yet.
Since both of these proof are quite involved and use fairly advanced machinery, I would be very pleased if someone could provide a more elementary proof for the case I described in my original question.
